# Pandas changing cell values dependent on other cell values in same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe in which one of my columns needs to be updated and changed based on a set of criteria and data the other columns in the row provide.

The row in question is List Price Currency.

If the columns before it (Price Book Name) contains Amer, I want the List Price Currency to be updated to USD List. If the price book doesn't say Amer, I want the Currency to be updated to Intl USD. Otherwise, if the Price Book name contains GBP, I just want to change that to UK list, and EUR to Euro List.

I tried writing a small for loop to go through each List Price Currency and update it based on what the Price Book Name says, but it isn't actually doing anything to the cells in the column.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
for column in datagrouped['List Price Currency']:
    if 'List Price Currency' == "USD":
        if 'Price Book Name'.str.contains("Amer"):
             'List Price Currency' == "US List"
        else: 'List Price Currency' == "Intl USD"
    if "List Price Currency" == "GBP":
             "List Price Currency" == "UK List"
    if "List Price Currency" == "EUR":
             "List Pricy Currency" == "Euro List"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the currencies in the Book_Name_Price column you can use the map function as shown below:

```
    import pandas as pd

    # Create data frame
    price_book_name = ['Amer', 'I-USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'Amer' , 'GBP', 'I-USD']
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Price_Book_Name': price_book_name})

    # Create an empty column by broadcasting
    df['List_Price_Currency'] = ''

    # Create a dictionary to map onto data frame
    curr_cat = {'Amer': 'US List', 'I-USD': 'Intl USD', 'GBP': 'UK list', 'EUR': 'Euro list'}

    # Map dictionary on to List_Price_Currency
    df['List_Price_Currency'] = df['Price_Book_Name'].map(curr_cat)

    print(df)

      Price_Book_Name List_Price_Currency
    0            Amer             US List
    1           I-USD            Intl USD
    2             GBP             UK list
    3             EUR           Euro list
    4             EUR           Euro list
    5            Amer             US List
    6             GBP             UK list
    7           I-USD            Intl USD
```